# How to fetch image from local server with Volley

Tags: android, image, ftp, android-volley

I can fetch image successfully with volley ( http url )

But what i want is to fetch image from local server ( windows pc). its url is like file://PCname/....

Error is ftpurlconnection class cannot be cast to httpurlconnection class.

Here is the class that goes for http :

```js
public class HurlStack implements HttpStack {
    private static final String HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE = "Content-Type";
    private final HurlStack.UrlRewriter mUrlRewriter;
    private final SSLSocketFactory mSslSocketFactory;

    public HurlStack() {
        this((HurlStack.UrlRewriter)null);
    }

    public HurlStack(HurlStack.UrlRewriter urlRewriter) {
        this(urlRewriter, (SSLSocketFactory)null);
    }

    public HurlStack(HurlStack.UrlRewriter urlRewriter, SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory) {
        this.mUrlRewriter = urlRewriter;
        this.mSslSocketFactory = sslSocketFactory;
    }

    public HttpResponse performRequest(Request<?> request, Map<String, String> additionalHeaders) throws IOException, AuthFailureError {
        String url = request.getUrl();
        HashMap map = new HashMap();
        map.putAll(request.getHeaders());
        map.putAll(additionalHeaders);
        if(this.mUrlRewriter != null) {
            String parsedUrl = this.mUrlRewriter.rewriteUrl(url);
            if(parsedUrl == null) {
                throw new IOException("URL blocked by rewriter: " + url);
            }

            url = parsedUrl;
        }

        URL parsedUrl1 = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = this.openConnection(parsedUrl1, request);
        Iterator protocolVersion = map.keySet().iterator();

        while(protocolVersion.hasNext()) {
            String responseCode = (String)protocolVersion.next();
            connection.addRequestProperty(responseCode, (String)map.get(responseCode));
        }

        setConnectionParametersForRequest(connection, request);
        ProtocolVersion protocolVersion1 = new ProtocolVersion("HTTP", 1, 1);
        int responseCode1 = connection.getResponseCode();
        if(responseCode1 == -1) {
            throw new IOException("Could not retrieve response code from HttpUrlConnection.");
        } else {
            BasicStatusLine responseStatus = new BasicStatusLine(protocolVersion1, connection.getResponseCode(), connection.getResponseMessage());
            BasicHttpResponse response = new BasicHttpResponse(responseStatus);
            response.setEntity(entityFromConnection(connection));
            Iterator i$ = connection.getHeaderFields().entrySet().iterator();

            while(i$.hasNext()) {
                Entry header = (Entry)i$.next();
                if(header.getKey() != null) {
                    BasicHeader h = new BasicHeader((String)header.getKey(), (String)((List)header.getValue()).get(0));
                    response.addHeader(h);
                }
            }

            return response;
        }
    }

    private static HttpEntity entityFromConnection(HttpURLConnection connection) {
        BasicHttpEntity entity = new BasicHttpEntity();

        InputStream inputStream;
        try {
            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException var4) {
            inputStream = connection.getErrorStream();
        }

        entity.setContent(inputStream);
        entity.setContentLength((long)connection.getContentLength());
        entity.setContentEncoding(connection.getContentEncoding());
        entity.setContentType(connection.getContentType());
        return entity;
    }

    protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
        return (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    }

    private HttpURLConnection openConnection(URL url, Request<?> request) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection connection = this.createConnection(url);
        int timeoutMs = request.getTimeoutMs();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(timeoutMs);
        connection.setReadTimeout(timeoutMs);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        if("https".equals(url.getProtocol()) && this.mSslSocketFactory != null) {
            ((HttpsURLConnection)connection).setSSLSocketFactory(this.mSslSocketFactory);
        }

        return connection;
    }

    static void setConnectionParametersForRequest(HttpURLConnection connection, Request<?> request) throws IOException, AuthFailureError {
        switch(request.getMethod()) {
        case -1:
            byte[] postBody = request.getPostBody();
            if(postBody != null) {
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", request.getPostBodyContentType());
                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                out.write(postBody);
                out.close();
            }
            break;
        case 0:
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            break;
        case 1:
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            addBodyIfExists(connection, request);
            break;
        case 2:
            connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
            addBodyIfExists(connection, request);
            break;
        case 3:
            connection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
            break;
        case 4:
            connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            break;
        case 5:
            connection.setRequestMethod("OPTIONS");
            break;
        case 6:
            connection.setRequestMethod("TRACE");
            break;
        case 7:
            addBodyIfExists(connection, request);
            connection.setRequestMethod("PATCH");
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown method type.");
        }

    }

    private static void addBodyIfExists(HttpURLConnection connection, Request<?> request) throws IOException, AuthFailureError {
        byte[] body = request.getBody();
        if(body != null) {
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", request.getBodyContentType());
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            out.write(body);
            out.close();
        }

    }

    public interface UrlRewriter {
        String rewriteUrl(String var1);
    }
}
```

What i changed , but failed :

```js
public class HurlStackFtp extends HurlStack {

    @Override
    public HttpResponse performRequest(Request<?> request, Map<String, String> additionalHeaders)
            throws IOException, AuthFailureError {

        String urlString = request.getUrl();
        if (urlString != null && urlString.startsWith("file://")) {
            return performFTPRequest(request, additionalHeaders);
        } else {
            return super.performRequest(request, additionalHeaders);
        }
    }


    public HttpResponse performFTPRequest(Request<?> request, Map<String, String> additionalHeaders)
            throws IOException, AuthFailureError {
        String url = request.getUrl();
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.putAll(request.getHeaders());
        map.putAll(additionalHeaders);
        // UrlRewriter not supported

        InputStream input = getStreamFromFTP(url);
        StatusLine responseStatus = new BasicStatusLine(new ProtocolVersion("HTTP", 1, 1),
                /*connection.getResponseCode()*/200, /*connection.getResponseMessage()*/"OK");
        BasicHttpResponse response = new BasicHttpResponse(responseStatus);
        response.setEntity(makeEntity(input));
        return response;
    }

    public static InputStream getStreamFromFTP(String url) throws IOException {
        URL parsedUrl = new URL(url);
        URLConnection cn = parsedUrl.openConnection();
        cn.connect();
        return cn.getInputStream();
    }

    private static HttpEntity makeEntity(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        BasicHttpEntity entity = new BasicHttpEntity();
        entity.setContent(inputStream);
        entity.setContentLength(inputStream.available());
        entity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream"); // sigh...
        return entity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PICASSO library for Android.

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Example :

1) If its URL (Server Image) then

> Picasso.with(context).load("http:/myserver.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);

2) If its URI (Local Image) then

> File f = new File(uri)
>
> Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(f).into(imageView);

Comment: the url i want to load is file:/myserver.com/DvpvklR.png

Comment: Is it URI or URL ?

Comment: its not workting. the image is getting fetched from http url but not from ftp:// or file://

Answer (score 0):

The url which you are using is **file:/myserver.com/DvpvklR.png** 
You will not be able to access this in your emulator or device as in both the cases the OS is different, emulator(kind of VM), device(separate machine), so in any case it is not possible.
To make it possible you need install some server(Tomcat, Apache, or in windows IIS) in your local machine and put your images in the respective server's   but when accessing from your Android you have to do with the local IP of machine the **http://l192.168.100.6** which refers to the device itself.

You can find out what your IP is by typing ipconfig in the command line.

Comment: i did all that and its working good. i can fetch text from local database , the problem is only the image url i cannot access it from http. its in the hard disk of windows pc shared location

Comment: is the path for image is static or you are getting it from the database, if yes the can you just show me the way you are getting it. and which server you are using?

Comment: image path is static and i want to fetch that image  from a windows pc , its url is like file://192.168.1.20/a.jpg

Comment: if you are getting it via HTTP then what;s the problem , go with it. anyway you still want to go with FTP then i guess ftp will need credentials in order to make the connection with that machine, so you have to provide that thing, only then you will be able achieve what you want, here are some links that might help you   http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/use-urlconnection-to-download-file-from-ftp-server               http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/java-ftp-file-download-tutorial-and-example